# iOS Safari VoiceOver - How to read dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, accessibility, voiceover

After executing following code (https://output.jsbin.com/refezujebi):

**Actual result:** 
Swipe right from "first title" will cause VoiceOver to read "second title".

**Expected result:**
Swipe right from "first title" will cause VoiceOver to read "loaded".

Note: dynamic div is initially empty. Is it possible to get the expected behavior?

```html
<html dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <h2>first title</h2>
    <div id="dynamic"></div>
    <h2>second title</h2>
    <script>
      setTimeout(() =>{
        const element = document.querySelector('#dynamic');
        element.innerHTML = 'loaded';
      }, 2000)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Another reproduction https://jsfiddle.net/eLjknf19/14/. It will read some label every time.

Comment: I have not found the solution to the problem posted above

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to look into [ARIA live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)

Basically you add a tag that explains to screen readers that you want changes to that element to be monitored and how you want them to be treated.

```
<div role="region" aria-live="polite">
   //monitor changes in here
</div>
```

The above would check for changes to the content and announce it.

Notice the `polite` - that is saying 'only announce when it does not interfere with the natural flow of things' so if the user is already having something read out it doesn't interrupt.

The link above explains in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, thats not exactly what the question is. I don't want new content to be announced, I just want it to be included in the "accessibility swipe" order. even after doing this you would not be able to swipe into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
In order to make voice-over detect changes in dynamic content you need to delete it and insert it again.
Here's snippet demonstrating what do I mean.

```js
const button = $('button')
button.on('click', change)

function change(){
 const label = $('#label')
  label.empty().text('new label'); // remove the node and then reinserts it with new label text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="label">
 some label
</h1>

<button onclick="change()">
 TEST
</button>
```

Here's solution to OP's problem.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <h2>first title</h2>
    <div id="dynamic"></div>
    <h2>second title</h2>
    <script>
      setTimeout(() =>{
        const element = $('#dynamic');
        element.empty();
        element.html('loaded');
      }, 2000)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works because label has content "some label". if it was initially empty you probably would hit the same issue as I posted.

Comment: @JoseCh. I have added another snippet solving your issue. I have tested it on iOS 13 and it is working